# How to implement local push notification in cordova application

Tags: cordova

Notification will be generating from the application data only.
Want to raise newsfeeds/notification after some specific time interval as well by some data events triggers. Pls. provide concrete solution/guidelines.

Comment: @Daniel , You must be in hurry to write the comment, I have asked for the **solution or guidelines** not to write code. If you don't know, better skip the question

Comment: Not in a hurry, this just isn't a code writing service. Do research yourself and ask a question with  [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I did my research and,  unfortunately, didn't get anything about it. We all are here to exchange and gain knowledge. All are enough mature to understand what StackOverflow for or what should ask. As I said earlier, if don't know the answer better skip the question. Hope you get my points.

Comment: You have not demonstrated your research, nor provided examples of code of your efforts. Voting to close question for being too broad.

Comment: There is always the simple thing to quit is give diplomatic answers. if you don't know why you doing such useless thing. if you know how to do that it good. Don't make the useless points on it. time will  teach you.

Comment: I'm sorry to say but you've misunderstood the purpose of this website. It is not a code writing service. Head over to http://stackoverflow.com/tour, read, take your time, and make yourself at home :)

Comment: Try out [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification) plugin.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found plugin which allows to manage and control local notifications and feeds in the application locally.

cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git

Thanks.